# Using jQuery to read from .serialize to populate a form

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

First off, I'm a but of a JS newbie. I have form1 asking for a user's email address which I am serializing.  What I need is to take this single field of data and unserialize it in a field in a more complex form2 which is spawned in a lightbox when a user submits the form1.

I have the serialization done, and the lightbox done, but I can't figure out how to grab the email address submitted in form1 and pre-populate the email field in form2 with that data.  Any help would be appreciated.

Code for the two forms is below.  (leaving out lightbox as it doesn't apply).  Basically, I need to get the 'email' from 'form1' into the 'email' field in 'form2'

```
<form action="#" id="form1">
   <label>email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit" />
</form>

<form action="#" id="form2">
   <label>Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
   <label>Zip Code:</label> <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"/>
   <strong>Choose a Newsletter </strong>
   <ul><li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="Weekly" id="Weekly"><label>Weekly</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="Daily" id="Daily"><label>Daily</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="Monthly" id="Monthly"><label>Monthly</label></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could help a little more if you showed more code, but this is essentially what you need to do.

You have the value of `email` in both its raw and serialized form.  Since `form2` is in a lightbox, it is really on the same page.  So, you can easily change the value of the email field within `form2`.

You would do this with the `.val()` jQuery function like so: `$("#form2 #email").val(email);`

Now obviously you're going to need to substitute out the jQuery selector (`#form2 #email`) to something that actually fits the new email field in `form2`.  You will also need to change `email` within the `.val()` function to be whichever variable you assigned as the email address from `form1`.

### EDIT

With the addition of your code, I am able to offer a little bit more - thanks!

This code will run when you submit the first form and will place the value of form1's email into form2.

```
$("#form1").submit(function(sent){

    // Sets the value of emailvalue to the current email address
    var emailValue = $("#form1 #email").val();
    // Places the value of emailValue into the email field in form2
    $("#form2 #email").val(emailValue);

});
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback and suggested solution.  I added the code for the two forms above in the hopes of getting an answer more suited to my exact situation.  Thanks

Comment: @NateLandau I've added some code which copies the value of the email and places into the second email field.

Comment: @NateLandau I would sure appreciate you marking this as the answer if this helped you out.